# Import set of builtin functions from a python file to another python file

Tags: python, file

I have set of inbuilt functions in 'pythonfile1.py' located at '/Users/testuser/Documents', the file contains

```
import os
import sys
import time
```

Now i want to import 'pythonfile1.py' to 'pythonfile2.py', which is located at '/Users/testuser/Documents/execute'
I have tried with my following code and it didn't work:

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = '/Users/testuser/Documents'
import pythonfile1.py
print os.getcwd()
```

I want it to print the current working directory

Comment: Try printing sys.path after you modify it.

Comment: For a start (may not be all) change 'import pythonfile1.py' to 'from pythonfile1 import *'

Comment: Please include the error you receive when running the code! Your import statements is wrong...

Comment: Also, [what are you trying to achieve](http://xyproblem.info)? You could simply import `os` directly to call `os.getcwd()`, there's no effect from importing `pythonfile1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. Basically, there are two things 'wrong'.

- First, your import statement is broken:

  ```
  import pythonfile1.py
  ```

  This specifies a **file** name, not a **module** name - modules don't contain dots and extensions. This is important because dots indicate *sub*-modules of packages. Your statement is trying to import module `py` from package `pythonfile1`. Change it to

  ```
  import pythonfile1
  ```
- Second, there's no need to fetch builtins from another module. You can just import them again.

  ```
  # pythonfile1
  import os
  print 'pythonfile1', os.getcwd()  # assuming py2 syntax

  # pythonfile2
  import os
  print 'pythonfile2', os.getcwd()
  ```

  If you *really* want to use `os` from `pythonfile1`, you can do so:

  ```
  # pythonfile2
  import os
  import pythonfile1
  print 'pythonfile2', os.getcwd()
  print 'pythonfile1->2', pythonfile1.os.getcwd()
  ```

  Note that `os` and `pythonfile1.os` in `pythonfile2` are the exact same module.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to import stuff from another file, you should use python modules.

If you will create file named **init**.py then the execute folder becomes a module.
After that you can use

```
from .pythonfile1 import function_name
```

or you can use

```
from .pythonfile1 import *
```

which imports all, but better solution is name everything you want to use explicitly

you can find more about modules in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: The statement `from .pythonfile1 import function_name` won't work in his `pythonfile2`, since it's in a subdirectory of execute. It should be `from execute.pythonfile1 import function_name` instead. But I'm suspecting turning `execute` into a package might be what he's up to indeed.